# How to change date format in file name using bash/linux?

Tags: linux, bash, batch-rename, date-format

Is there an easy way to change in a linux console the date format in a file name?

Eg. I have a bunch of files which contain a date (`DD-MM-YYYY`) in the file name like:

```
example_20-08-2016.pdf
```

and I want to change it to `YYYY-MM-DD`:

```
example_2016-08-20.pdf
```

*I was looking for a bash script I can must apply in the a folder with several files.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Perl's `rename`:

```
rename 's/([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})/$3-$2-$1/' *.pdf
```

See: `man rename`

Comment: Thx, that's what I was looking for. I didn't know that it is that easy. I changed the example code a little to make it more general and to apply it on all files which the ending `*.pdf`.